# Create a list of multiples of 3 from 0 to 20

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement, range

The code directions are (Create a list of multiples of 3 from 0 to 20.)  the style is the needed is below.  For so reason after the 'range' and before 'if', something is missing.  Please help mee.  Thank you

```
a = [i for i in range(20) ? if i % 3 ==0]
```

Comment: Nothing's missing, I don't think? Just remove the `?` and it looks good to me.

Comment: (Note that you're not considering 20 as a possible value: if you want a range of 0-20 inclusive you need `range(21)`. But that doesn't matter for divisible-by-3.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is a ternary operator in other language but in python it's just `x if a else y`.

For list comprehension`[ret for ret in range(X) if_statement]` is equivalent to:

```
l = []
for ret in range(X):
    if_statement:
        l.append(ret)
```

So you can do this:

```
In [1]: a = [i for i in range(20) if i % 3 ==0]                                                   

In [2]: a                                                                                         
Out[2]: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```

But you can also utilize the `range` function and specify a step size:

```
In [3]: list(range(0, 20, 3))                                                                     
Out[3]: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]
```